# Automatic Heat Weighting: Failed to find a solution for one or more bones error

Tags: armature, weight-painting

Please don't mark this question as a duplicate, because solutions for other questions with the same error, doesn't work for me.

So I have a character model, created via ManuelBasioniLab, and I want to make an armature with automatic weights for it, so I created few bones to test that it will be working, and it doesn't work because of error.

I tried to:

- Delete half of the mesh and using mirror modifier
- Use Remove Doubles (on the first try deleted about 130 vertices)
- Use subsurf modifier
- Use decimate modifier

Nothing seems to be working, the error is still showing.

Link to the model: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cqahidxh39zyav/character.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Changing the scale of mesh and armature to bigger solved my problem.